# Grabbing current user.config path (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, basic, my.settings

Is there a way of grabbing the location of the My.Settings user.config location? So for example I want to be able in VB to grab the path of the user.cofing file path to a string

The reason I ask is that I have an application where the user.config file is backed up and then restored, the issue is that with the my.settings folder structure it uses a unique hash with the folder name meaning that I cannot write into the code a static folder path, instead I need to be able to grab the location of the user.config **OR** be able to get the folder name of the application AppData.

Any ideas?

To put this in perspective, currently I'm using something like this:

Dim filePath As String

```
        filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\My_App\My_App.exe_Url_<the_hash_that_changes_causing_issues>\1.0.0.0\user.config"
```

Because of the hash change this will not always work

Comment: What kind of application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing this code:

```vb
Dim mainConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
Dim userConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming)
Dim userLocalConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)

Console.WriteLine(mainConfig.FilePath)
Console.WriteLine(userConfig.FilePath)
Console.WriteLine(userLocalConfig.FilePath)
```

You'll need to reference System.Configuration.dll and import `System.Configuration`.